# which algorithm should be used to predict the future status given data from past status?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to write the code to forcast the status. The status 0 means non-active, 1 means active. I would like to preicit the future month (e.g 2016/6/1), the status should be "0" or "1".  What algorithm could be used in such a situation?

```
date       status
2016/1/10   0
2016/1/19   0
2016/2/2    1
2016/2/10   1
2016/3/1    0
2016/4/2    1
2016/4/3    0
2016/5/4    0
2016/5/5    1
```

Comment: Have you collected any other relevant data other than `date` and `status`?

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you want to implement an algorithm which gives yes/no (0/1)output

this is called classification problem

there are many classification algorithms available like

"Logistic regression , Support vector machine ,Neural networks and etc..."

you can use any one of them, based on you training examples one performs well than others

here is the link for logistic regression i would prefer to use this algorithm

http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf